# How do you make a matplotlib plot with two panels at the top and one centered at the bottom, all with the same size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For the following MWE I'm using the functions defined in [this docs page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/mosaic.html). Consider the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# Helper function used for visualization in the following examples
def identify_axes(ax_dict, fontsize=48):
    """
    Helper to identify the Axes in the examples below.

    Draws the label in a large font in the center of the Axes.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax_dict : dict[str, Axes]
        Mapping between the title / label and the Axes.
    fontsize : int, optional
        How big the label should be.
    """
    kw = dict(ha="center", va="center", fontsize=fontsize, color="darkgrey")
    for k, ax in ax_dict.items():
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, k, transform=ax.transAxes, **kw)

axd = plt.figure(layout="constrained").subplot_mosaic(
    """
    AC
    DD
    """
)
identify_axes(axd)
```

This produces this figure:

[image]
Basically I'm trying to reproduce something like this figure:

My question is: how can I produce a similar figure, but with the plot at the bottom having the same size as the other two, and still being centered? For the life of me I can't figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

axd = plt.figure(layout="constrained").subplot_mosaic(
    """
    AABB
    .CC.
    """
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware you have only "doubles"! Ugh, I feel stupid... Thanks for the answer!